# Hyperledger Composer: how to define relationships

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am a little confused about how to define relationships in a Hyperledger Composer .cto file. Please see my specific questions below:

Here I am pasting parts of the .cto file found here https://github.com/IBM/Decentralized-Energy-Composer/blob/master/models/model.cto :

```
participant Resident identified by residentID {
    o String residentID
    o String firstName
    o String lastName
    --> Coins coins
    --> Cash cash
    --> Energy energy
}

asset Coins identified by coinsID {
    o String coinsID
    o Double value
    o String ownerID
    o OwnerEntity ownerEntity

}

asset Energy identified by energyID {
    o String energyID
    o String units
    o Double value
    o String ownerID
    o OwnerEntity ownerEntity
} 

asset Cash identified by cashID {
    o String cashID
    o String currency
    o Double value
    o String ownerID
    o OwnerEntity ownerEntity
}
```

Should this be read as `a Resident owns assets which are Coins, Cash and Energy` ? Can this be written the other way around (see below)?

```
participant Resident identified by residentID {
    o String residentID
    o String firstName
    o String lastName

}

asset Coins identified by coinsID {
    o String coinsID
    o Double value
    -->Resident owner

}

asset Energy identified by energyID {
    o String energyID
    o String units
    o Double value
    --> Resident owner
} 

asset Cash identified by cashID {
    o String cashID
    o String currency
    o Double value
    --> Resident owner
}
```

So, this basically says that each asset is owned by someone. Which design is considered better and why? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The second design, most likely, as it is more `normalized` from a design perspective. (Should imagine the current design is level-set for a sample demo as opposed to exhaustive design in readiness for something greater). Business network models (amongst other things) describe the `participants`, `assets`, and `transactions` - the modeled network - a declaration of the resources and their field/attributes/types - and of course any relationships - ie not too dissimilar to an `old school` database design, generally speaking.  Better explanation [here (scroll down)](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language.html).

**The relationship says:**

1. This resource - has a relationship to another resource.
2. The linked resource can be accessed from 'this' resource (eg.
   code-wise you can retrieve field values, without resorting to going
   directly to that registry to search and retrieve the record).

In design 2 above: classically, the `owner` field (in the `assets`) is a relationship field - and maps to a `participant` record (by its identifying field) in the referenced participant class. In your transaction logic, you can check the value of `owner.firstName` for the related participant (one example).

The relationship is unidirectional. By adding the relationship field, the participant (in the case of #2) may be referenced from any of the above asset resource types (eg. from within your transaction processing logic/code, part of your smart contract). Relationships are not enforced (it's not a relational database) but you can add logic yourself for checks when adding/removing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more question: what if an asset can have an owner, but the owner could be a resident, or a bank, or a company. In this scenario, an asset would have a relationship with 3 participants, but two of the relationships will be NULL because an asset can be owned by only 1 participant. Is that reasonable?

Comment: assume you meant relationship with 3 different participant `types` (in the asset model) and 'owned by only 1 participant type at a time'. But either way - yes, 2 can be NULL, if the 3rd is assigned (in your scenario).